# what is the difference between exit and std::exit in C++?

Tags: c++, exit

what is the difference between `exit` and `std::exit` in C++? I have researched it but i couldn't find anything.

What is the difference between these two codes:

**1:**

```
if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0)
{
    std::cout << "Error: Can't initialize the SDL \n";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

**2:**

```
if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0)
{
    std::cout << "Error: Can't initialize the SDL \n";
    std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: One lives in the `std` namespace, and the other does not. Which you get depends on the headers you include.

Comment: Both are exactly the same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They're two names for the same function that does the same things.

Note, however, that in C++ `std::exit`/`exit` (regardless of how you get to its name) does have some behavior that's not specified for the `exit` in the C library. In particular,

1. `exit` first destroys all objects with thread storage duration that are associated with the current thread.
2. Objects with static storage duration are destroyed, and any functions registered with `atexit` are invoked.

   - If one of these throws an exception that isn't caught, `terminate` is invoked.
3. After that we get the normal C behavior:

   - Open C streams are flushed if they have unwritten data, then they're closed.
   - Files created by calling `tmpfile` are removed.
   - Control is returned to the host environment, returning success or failure depending on the value passed in the call to `exit` (`0` or `EXIT_SUCCESS` => success, `EXIT_FAILURE` => failure, anything else is implementation defined).

Note in particular that local objects are *not* destroyed by any call to exit.

That means, in effect, that you should really forget all of the above, and simply *never* call `exit`/`std::exit` from C++ code. While the committee apparently feels that compatibility with C code is a strong enough motivation that they *need* to leave it in the standard, you certainly don't need to use it--and under almost any reasonably normal circumstances, you shouldn't. Destroying local objects on exit from a scope is an important enough part of C++ that a function like `exit` that removes this guarantee leads to almost nothing but headaches.

If you need behavior vaguely similar to that of `exit`, you normally want to do something like this:

```
struct my_exit : public std::exception { 
    int value;
    my_exit(int value) : value(value) {}
};

int main() { 
    try {
        // do normal stuff
    }

    catch(my_exit const &e) {
        return e.value;
    }
}
```

Then in the rest of the code where you would otherwise have called `exit`, you instead `throw my_exit(whatever_value);`. This way, all the local variables will be destroyed (i.e., stack unwinding will happen) and *then* you'll do a normal exit to the environment.

Answer (score 9):

`exit` (when using a C++ compiler) is "borrowed" from the C standard library via the header `stdlib.h`.

`std::exit` is the C++ standard library version; defined in `cstdlib`.

In C++ you ought to use the latter, but the two functions do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real difference. Unless you have different functions named `exit` in different scopes/namespaces (and if you do; well, I don't know what to say then - just don't), `exit()`, `::exit()` and `std::exit()` is the same thing.

You usually don't *want* to call `exit` though, since doing so terminates the program without running local and global destructors (just `atexit` registered functions). *Sometimes* (rarely) that's what you want, but generally not - you want to return from `main` instead.

Answer (score 1):

When you have declare before : `using namespace std;` there is no difference between `std::exit` and `exit`

This declaration permit to avoid the writing of the prefix std.

So you can also write `cout` instead of `std::cout`